# Почему ругается на неверный формат строки?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Исключение неверный формат строки,проблема в реализации функции Execute.
Что я делаю не так?
Блокнотовский файл не могу залить но вот его содержимое
0.5; ros

Код программы

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        RefLab.ShowMethodsWithString("LabWork_1.Foo");
        RefLab.Execute("LabWork_1.Foo", "Method4", "1.txt");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class RefLab
{
    public static void ShowMethodsWithString(string className)
    {
        var ass = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        var type = ass.GetType(className);
        Console.WriteLine("Метод содержащий строковые параметры:\n");
        try
        {
            foreach (MemberInfo m in type.GetMethods())//перебор методов
            {
                var found = false;
                foreach (ParameterInfo pi in ((MethodInfo)m).GetParameters())//параметры в методе
                    if (pi.ParameterType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }

                if (found)
                    Console.WriteLine("Method {0}", m.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
    }

    public static void Execute(string className, string methodName, string paramFile)
    {
        var assem = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        var obj = assem.CreateInstance(className);
        var mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
        var Params = new List<object>();
        var paramInfos = mi.GetParameters();
        var @params = File.ReadAllLines(paramFile);
        for (int i = 0; i < @params.Length; i++)
        Params.Add(Convert.ChangeType(@params[i], paramInfos[i].ParameterType));-------Само собой он выкидывает исключения на этой строке
        mi.Invoke(obj, Params.ToArray<object>());
    }
}

public class Foo
{

    public int Method1()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public string Method2(string str,string str1)
    {
        return str;
    }

    public double Method3(double val)
    {
        return val;
    }

    public void Method4(double val, string str)
    {

       Console.WriteLine(val + " ");
    }
}
```

Само задание
Разработать утилитарный класс «**ReflLab**» содержащий две статические функции:

1. функцию «**ShowMethodsWithString**», отображающую список методов, содержащих хотя бы один параметр типа «**System.String**». Поиск методов со строковыми параметрами осуществлять в классе, имя которого передается в функцию «**ShowMethodsWithString**»;
2. функцию «**Execute**», осуществляющую вызов указанного метода по его имени. Функция должна принимать три параметра: имя класса (**className**), имя метода в классе (**methodName**) и имя файла на диске (**paramFile**), содержащего значения для параметров вызываемого метода. Значения для параметров записаны в файле построчно (одна строка для каждого параметра). Считать также, что набор типов данных, допустимых в параметрах вызываемого метода, ограничен основными базовыми типами данных (**int, double, bool, char, string**).

Comment: а зачем `Convert.ChangeType` вызываете? Ну и раз ошибка: _неверный формат строки_ стоит проверить строку

Comment: Преподаватель сказал что файл по умолчанию должен быть правильным и там может хранится любой из 5-ти видов переменных параметр

Comment: пример содержания этого файла, и пример содержания когда падает

Comment: @Dmitry, затер все мои правки :-D

Comment: и почему _Само собой он выкидывает исключения на этой строке_?

Comment: @Grundy, я не специально, правили видать одновременно, но только для моих правок прув не нужен

Comment: Я не могу пока разобраться как сюда залить простой текстовый файл

но вот его содержимое.

0,5;
ros

Я ссылаюсь на Method4 где у меня double и string
Меня обвинили в том что я не знаю что такое значение параметров.
Но не сказали как правильно якобы писать,может быть я неправильно записываю в файл значения параметров,но кажется правильно.

Comment: @Dmitry, ага, это-то понятно :-) но все равно

Comment: @beginner, содержимое в пост добавь, а не в коммент

Comment: Смог залить только скрин программы,кода и содержимого блокнота.
Разобрался как залить скрин.
как залить блокнот пока разбираюсь

Comment: @beginner, не нужно добавлять текстовый файл, достаточно выложить его содержимое :-)

Comment: попробуй воспользоваться отладчиком :-)

Comment: beginner, если вам ответ помог - его надо отметить такой зеленой галочкой...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) В текстовом файле в каждой строке должен бы только один параметр и без каких либо разделительных знаков (в Вашем случае без точки с запятой):

0.5

ros

...и тд.

2) В `ChangeType` укажите нужную культуру (либо используйте инвариант):

```
Params.Add(Convert.ChangeType(@params[i], paramInfos[i].ParameterType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` будет ждать точку для разделения дробной части

Comment: и кстати без пустых строк между параметрами

Comment: у автора как раз таки точка является разделителем, да и привел я инвариант лишь в качестве примера

Comment: честно говоря мне показалось в блокноте у него запятая на скрине стоит, да и в комментариях он тоже запятую в качестве разделителя использовал

Comment: забавно, а в посте - через точку

Comment: Снова ругается
Теперь на цикл.
Картинку обновил.

Comment: CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB") попробуйте, если у Вас в файле действительно "точка" а не "запятая"

Comment: Спасибо большое всем!Помогло

А мне сейчас лучше прочитать про эти культуры и про их связь с  рефлексией

Comment: @beginner, абсолютно никакой связи у культур с рефлексией